# Angular2 Hero Tutorial - hero class

Tags: angular

In the section where the hero class is temporarily stored on app.component.ts, I'm not sure where to paste the script below where it says we have to refactor.

hero: Hero = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Windstorm'
};

Putting this in the app.component.ts file brings up an error. In the final version, it seems like this class is a standalone file, but right now, I'm supposed to be able to see the name of the hero in Chrome while its still in app.component.ts. Help?

EDIT: here's the whole code.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

hero: Hero = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Windstorm'
};

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1><h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>'
})

export class AppComponent `enter code here`{
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  hero = 'Windstorm';
}
```

Comment: It would probably be helpful to post the error you are getting.

Comment: TS
Error
Unused label.at line 8 col 1
TS
Error
Invalid left-hand side of assignment expression.at line 8 col 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. The first one is that you defined property `hero` outside of the class, and the other one is assignment `hero = 'Windstorm'`. You class should look like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class Hero {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1><h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>'
})
export class AppComponent {
    hero: Hero = {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Windstorm'
    };

    title = 'Tour of Heroes';
}
```

This should make it work. You initially assigned a string to a property `hero` making it implicitly a string type, but then you call `hero.name` expecting it to be an object of type `Hero`.

Comment: Thanks. I think this works. I agree, I found the hero property to be odd from the original tutorial.

Comment: What threw me off is the instruction from the Angular 2 tutorial: "Now that we have a Hero class, let’s refactor our component’s hero property to be of type Hero. Then initialize it with an id of 1 and the name, "Windstorm"." I wasn't sure what it meant by "refactor".

Comment: When you reach to a. Ertain point in development, you want to reorganize and rearrange your code, either the logic or organize types and onjects into files. That is a broad explanation about refactoring.

Comment: @HuseinRoncevic As per the tutorial, https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1, I have found Hero.ts as class file and the assigning the `hero` property as `hero: Hero ={}`. What is the need of the Hero.ts? If I use `hero = {}` itself, it is working fine. Then why should I use `Hero.ts` class file?

Comment: @Butterfly You don’t have to but in that case you `hero` object will be of type `any` and you lose strongly typed object signature. In such a small example this is not a big deal but on larger projects and more complex models you might not want an object of type `any`.

Answer (score 2):

Your error here is that you declared `Hero` as a class and you can't create a class on the fly.

`Hero` is an interface in the tutorial, to be able to create it on the fly.

simply replace

```
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

by

```
export interface Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

and your code will work. Because if you want to create a hero using the class, you'll have to do this:

```
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

let hero:Hero = new Hero();
hero.id= 1;
hero.name="Windstorm";
```

Here is the whole code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export interface Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

hero

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1><h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>'
})

export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Tour of Heroes';
    hero: Hero = {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Windstorm'
    };
}
```

Comment: Basically, you're saying if I want to create a class, I use the "export class Hero" and put it into a separate .ts file. If I want to inline it into app.component.ts, I would have to use "export interface Hero"?

Comment: The instructions on the Angular website doesn't make that class. It says to create a class but within app.component.ts near the top where "import" lines are at. I'm not sure why that instruction is the way it is.

Comment: the export keyword is optional here, it depends on wether you want to use this element (can be a class, an interface or a variable) in another .ts file. What I'm saying here is that you need to use an interface as type if you want to declare your hero the way you did it on the example.

Comment: ok. well, at least this portion of the tutorial taught me you can either export using class or interface embedded. tutorials are supposed to be easy damn it lol

Comment: Supamiu - can you paste the whole code page that you're proposing? I tried it and it doesn't work. I'll put the answer check back in your queue once you do. I'm looking for the answer which you use "interface" and not create a separate class module/page.Thx.

Comment: I pasted it, but the whole point of my answer is the interface part, I repeat: you should never create a class on the fly, it will not add the class's behaviour (A.K.A its methods) to your object and will create problems (you'll have some "unable to find property myFunction on object errors)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the right answer, but I'm sticking with it for now. I find it very odd the copying of the tutorial didn't work but from the glimpse of it, what the tutorial wanted me to do didn't make any sense. Based on my limited knowledge of Typescript, see my revision below. This only made sense given 1) the export class hero didn't make sense in this doc as suggested by the tutorial, declaring a variable hero would require "let" and 2) would have to modify the export AppComponent args.

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

```
let hero = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Windstorm'
};

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1><h2>{{hero}} details!</h2>'
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  hero = hero.name;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you don't need to export it ;or you can create new TS file and create new Class Called User like :

```
export class User {
 private name:string

 constructor...
 get && setter here...

    }
```

and import to your Component File and construct it